# Implementing ngx-editor on mat-table-cell Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material-table, ngx-editor

**I used ngx-editor on one component of my project in order to edit some data that needs to be saved. And then to be shown on a table (mat-table)**

[image]

**When showing this data on a table it is show like this:**
[image]

**How could I fix this in order to show the edited data on the mat-cell-table like it was entered?**

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already got to resolve your issue. But if you (or if anyone else on the internet) haven't managed to resolve it I can try to help.

What is happening here is ngx-editor stores the data generated inside a pure string, which you then have to parse into HTML and add it to the DOM. I will make an assumption and say you're directly adding the string into the mat-table by using `{{ editorContent }}` or something like that (or maybe `<table mat-table [dataSource]="editorContent">`). Anyhow, what you actually need to do is to use the `[innerHTML]` data binding which is available in any selector tag inside Angular in the following way:

```
<selector-tag [innerHTML]="editorContent"></selector-tag>
```

I'm sorry for not being 100% specific but it's hard to give an exact example without a glimpse of your actual code and how're is it that you're managing your data.

With that being said, I hope at least it has helped you or anyone else. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What Gonzalo says is basically right, you should bind that as `innerHTML` however you need to run that through [DOM sanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml) first (usually implemented as pipe).

```html
<mat-cell><span [innerHTML]="htmlval | safeHtmlPipe"></span></mat-cell>
```